# Octave Package install netcdf: nc-config not found

Tags: macos, package, octave, netcdf, octave-gui

I am using Octave(-gui) on Mac (OSX 10.15.7 Catalina) and try to install the `netcdf` package. I get an error that nc-config was not found.
My version of Octave is 6.1.0. I also tried installing from local tar.gz.
This is the output of my Octave console:

```
>> pkg install -forge netcdf

configure: error: nc-config not found
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether clang++ -std=gnu++11 accepts -g... yes
checking for mkoctfile... /Applications/Octave-6.1.0.app/Contents/Resources/usr/Cellar/octave-octave-app@6.1.0/6.1.0/bin/mkoctfile-6.1.0
checking for nc-config... no

error: pkg: error running the configure script for netcdf.
error: called from
    configure_make at line 93 column 9
    install at line 196 column 7
    pkg at line 568 column 9
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Comment: have you installed a `*netcdf*devel*` package ?

Comment: On ubuntu: "Command 'nc-config' not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install libnetcdf-dev". You probably need the equivalent package on mac.

Comment: Thank you, there is a libnet package for OSX available which i installed on my system, but still get the same error. It seems that Octave does not find nc-config

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: This is an issue in Octave.app, not something you're doing wrong. Please swing by [the Octave.app Issue Page](https://github.com/octave-app/octave-app/issues/222) and discuss how this should be fixed.

<strike>This sounds like you need the `netcdf` system package installed. (This is the native NetCDF library on which the Octave `netcdf` package depends.) If you have Homebrew, you can install it with `brew install netcdf` and it might work.</strike>

Octave.app should probably bundle `netcdf` itself, so you don't need it installed on your system. You can open a request for that on [the Octave.app Issues page](https://github.com/octave-app/octave-app/issues).

Comment: Thank you! I already have netcdf installed via brew as you suggested, but i still get the exact same error. nc-config lies here: /usr/local/Cellar/netcdf/4.7.4_2/bin/nc-config

Comment: Hmm. Check to make sure that the Homebrew `netcdf` is "linked"? Try `which nc-config` and `ls -l $(which nc-config)` both from your Terminal and an Octave `system()` call. You should have a symlink like `/usr/local/bin/nc-config -> ../Cellar/netcdf/4.7.4_2/bin/nc-config` there.

Comment: Nevermind: Turns out this is actually an issue with Octave.app: because it is launched as a native Mac app, it doesn't pick up your shell configuration, which is how `/usr/local` gets pulled in. This is actually something we need to figure out how to address. Swing on by https://github.com/octave-app/octave-app/issues and report this as a bug in Octave.app and we'll figure out how to fix it.